# Laravel 5 MassAssignmentException on update with Fillable Already Set?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to run this:

```
$model->update(Input::all());
```

I already have `$fillable = ['field1', 'field2'];` set in the model

It's still throwing me a `MassAssignmentException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use $model->fill(Input::all()) instead of update. So it would look like this:

```
$model->fill(Input:all());
$model->save();
```

Comment: That's what update already does internally, anyway, found out my mistake was that I set the `$fillable` property as `protected` instead of `public`.

Comment: @Rob Actually `$fillable` doesn't need to be public

Comment: @lukasgeiter update did not work when it was set to `protected`.